# WebApi Authentication filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-authorization, iprincipal

Please I need your help to understand this issue..

am building an **Authorization server** (**ASP.Net WebApi hosted on IIS**) which responsible for generating jwt tokens based on ASPNet Identity and a **resource server** which is **ASP.Net WebApi OWIN self-Hosted** on a Windows Service.

my understanding is the **authorization filter** executes "**AuthenticateAsync**", if the filter successfully validates the token, the filter creates an **IPrincipal** and attaches it to the request.

Please i need to know in the scenario described above 
who is resposible for executing the AuthenticateAsync and loading the IPrincipal?  and how does it work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters